# Display in a column the first three letters of the name + id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using `Activeadmin` in rails. For example, I would like to display in a column the first three letters of the name + id
Here is a piece of code

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

 permit_params: email,: name,: firstname,: mailsent,: 
 email_confirmed,: adminuser,: approved

 index do
  column: email
  column: name
  column: firstname
  column: mailsent
  column: email_confirmed
  column: adminuser
  column: approved
  actions
 end
```

Comment: What is your question by the way?

Comment: How can i change column: email to display only the 3 first letters + id  ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
column "Custom Title" do |user|
  "#{user.name.first(3)-#{user.id}"
end
```

And, of course, I suggest you extract `"#{user.name.first(3)-#{user.id}"` to the User model or a decorator.